# Are Local Notifications backed up?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I have a need to post a local notification with a fire date in the far future. (Think months away.) I realize that won't fire if the app is deleted, that's ok.

But will it fire if the user has bought a new phone? (After backing up up their phone and restoring it from iTunes of course.)

Apple's docs aren't clear on this. I did see one blog that claimed you can delete the app and re-install it within 24 hours and still get the local notification to fire, but I've also not seen that in Apple's docs. And that still doesn't mean that the local notification will transfer to the new device.

I only care about iOS8 and iOS9.

Comment: Good find. I'll vote to close my question.